# PHP datetime between two 2 values

Tags: php, datetime

I'm making a scheduling application, and i'm stuck with the following logic.
I have an array of time slots, and i want to hide the time slot that are before 9:00am next day, if the current time is after 7:00pm. For example if the current timedate is 8/25/2014 7:01pm  , all time slots that are before 8/26/2014 9:00am shouldn't appear.

I tried this

```
if(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('7:00pm')) <= $from && $from <= date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+1 day 9:00am')) && $now > date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('7:00pm')))
                continue;
```

But `strtotime('7:00pm')` returning the current day at 7:00pm.

The question is how to get the datetime that means, the day before `$from`at 7:00pm ?

Comment: What is $from exactly? Just a day? A precise time?

Comment: a php date object, `$from = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $start_time);`

Comment: PHP does not have a date object. `date()` is a function that returns a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try concatenating the date $from with 7:00pm something like:

```
$start_date = $date('Y-m-d', $from)." "."7:00pm";
// then use it in strtotime
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($start_date));
```

Comment: I want the day before `$from `

Comment: For example if `$from` is 8/25/2014, i need the datetime to be 8/24/2014 7:00pm

Comment: @MahAbdelaziz No problem, hope it helps!